# How can select() wait on regular file descriptors (non-sockets)?

Tags: c, select, file-io

This is the code sample from "man select" plus a few lines to read an actual file which is being written to.  I suspected that when the `./myfile.txt` is written to, `select` would return that it can now read from that fd.  But what happens is that select constantly returns in the while loop so long as the txt file exists. I want it to only return when new data is written to the end of the file. I thought that is how it should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(void)
{
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int retval;

    int fd_file = open("/home/myfile.txt", O_RDONLY);

   /* Watch stdin (fd 0) to see when it has input. */
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(0, &rfds);
    FD_SET(fd_file, &rfds);

   /* Wait up to five seconds. */
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

   while (1)
   {
     retval = select(fd_file+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
     /* Don't rely on the value of tv now! */

     if (retval == -1)
        perror("select()");
     else if (retval)
        printf("Data is available now.\n");
        /* FD_ISSET(0, &rfds) will be true. */
     else
        printf("No data within five seconds.\n");
   }

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: So what is your question ? **Who said `select` should only work on sockets** ?

Comment: question edited. sorry for confusion.

Comment: `select` can be used on _any_ file-type descriptor, doesn't matter if it's a socket, file or pipe or any similar descriptor. However, you can not use it to monitor when a file has been written to, for that you have to use something OS specific, like on Linux you can use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

Comment: i understand the first part of your comment. But the i thought that the purpose of selecting on a socket was basically just listening for when data was written to the socket.  How is it different for a file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Disk files are always ready to read (but the read might return 0 bytes if you're already at the end of the file), so you can't use [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) on a disk file to find out when new data is added to the file.

POSIX says:

> File descriptors associated with regular files shall always select true for ready to read, ready to write, and error conditions.

Also, as [cnicutar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714501/cnicutar) pointed out in a now-deleted post, in general, you have to initialize the FD_SET on each iteration.  In your code, you are monitoring one fd, and that fd is always ready, so the FD_SET is not in fact changing.  However, if you have 5 decriptors to monitor, and `select` detects that only one is ready, then on the next iteration, only that one descriptor would be monitored (unless you reset the FD_SET).  This makes using `select` tricky.

Comment: AFAIK `poll` cant be used to watch regular file for changes as well. So the only way to go is `inotify`? The problem is `inotify`-based solution works with filepath, not with file-descriptors that are already open.